# Implementing an ArrayQueue in java need toString method

Tags: java, arrays, queue

I have an `ArrayQueue` I am implementing for a class in the java language.

I am storing transaction objects in the `ArrayQueue` and I am getting stuck at the `display()` method (aka my own `toString()`). But it is only returning the reference.

Here is my method:

```
//display the elements in the current queue
public String display() {

  String result = "";

  if(isEmpty()) {
        throw new EmptyQueueException("Queue is empty.");
  } else {
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       result += "[" + Q[(front + i) % capacity] + "] ";
     }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Does this mean I need a `toString()` method for my object and call it like: `System.out.println(arrayqueue.display().toString())`?

Answer (score 1):

If you override `toString()` for your `ArrayQueue` class, you can use:

```
System.out.println(arrayqueue);
```

But if you choose to call it `display()`, then yes you need this:

```
System.out.println(arrayqueue.display())
```

How else is the runtime environment supposed to know you wanted the string representation instead of the object reference?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean I need a toString() method for my object and call it like: System.out.println(arrayqueue.display().toString())?

No, since `display()` returns a `String`, `arrayqueue.display()` should be sufficient.  Are you perhaps trying to print the `toString()` value of `arrayqueue`?  Without overriding `toString()`, it will return the class name and hash code by default.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the code

```
result += "[" + Q[(front + i) % capacity] + "] ";
```

You are calling the toString() method on the object contained at that location in the Q array. Default object toString() will print its memory location. If you have different data already declared by your object to print, such as object.getClass() to print the objects class name for instance you won't have to override toString() but instead call that method within the above code. Of course if you want a custom string that better represents your object than its memory location, its good to override toString() within that object's class.